# NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type - Tomcat on linux server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7, http-status-code-415

I am sending some json data to POST url. This code works fine in local environment (tomcat + windows) but does not works on production env (Tomcat + linux). **Already referred to various links, but none helped me out.**

Issue os with production env, also i long back some files got deleted from server, i suspect tomcat might have got corrupted, but rest all url's are working fine. this is the new development i am doing.

Also there is same behavior if i hit through firefox rest client.

**Error**

**The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method**

**Jquery code**

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/add",
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            },
        success : function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);          
        }
    });
```

**Spring controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String addDishDetails(
            @RequestBody MyPojo pojo) {
        return "success";
    }
```

**pom.xml**

Also added below jars

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you using different major versions of Jackson? Those aren't compatible at all.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but this i added as a workaround after seeing thru some answers , before adding this, in local it works fine, but not in prod.

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. Don't hack around things. Use Jackson 2 exclusively. Then enable DEBUG logging on Spring and check what it spits out.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you mean to say " <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>   <version>1.9.13</version>" and "    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>    <version>2.0.0</version>"

Comment: No, you should have [these](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core) three at their most recent version. Get rid of the `org.codehaus` version entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comments and answer are worth reading and might be solution for few cases.

In my case, i had a property `Map<String,String>`, i need to ignore this.

so i added,

```
@JsonIgnore
Map<String,String>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error it says that the client not sending request in the type which server is expecting, client sending json and we have defined **cosumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE** what if we replace it with **MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON** only and also you specified the accept parameter so either remove it or add produce property to **application/json** in controller.

Comment: `consumes` expects a `String` value. `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` references an `enum`.